# How to positionate in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new with Tkinter and i want to create a "form" ( i doesnt really know how to call it) which write into database. I'm done with it, but i'm fustrated because of the layout.

I have this code which make the "form":

```
    self.parent.title("Pozi")
    self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=True)

    frame1 = Frame(self)
    frame1.pack(side = LEFT)

    lbl1 = Label(frame1, text = "ĂtadĂł kĂˇrtyĂˇja", width = 15)
    lbl1.pack(side = TOP, padx=5)

    atadoText = StringVar() 
    atadoText.set('')
    self.entry1 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=atadoText)
    self.entry1.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx=5)
    atadoText.trace('w',atado_enter)
    self.atadoText = atadoText  
    self.entry1.focus()

    frame2 = Frame(self)
    frame2.pack(side = RIGHT)

    lbl2 = Label(frame2, text = "ĂtvevĹ‘ kĂˇrtyĂˇja", width = 15)
    lbl2.pack(side = TOP, padx=5, expand=True)

    atvevoText = StringVar()
    atvevoText.set('')
    self.entry2 = Entry(frame2, textvariable = atvevoText)
    self.entry2.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx=5)
    atvevoText.trace('w', atvevo_enter)
    self.atvevoText = atvevoText

    frame3 = Frame(self)
    frame3.pack(side = RIGHT)

    lbl3 = Label(frame3, text = "ĂrvevĹ‘ kĂˇrtyĂˇja", width = 15)
    lbl3.pack(side = TOP, padx=5, expand=True)

    lblText = StringVar()
    lblText.set('')
    self.entry3 = Entry(frame3, textvariable = lblText)
    self.entry3.pack(side = TOP, padx=5, expand=True)
    lblText.trace('w', lbl_count)
    self.lblText = lblText


    lbl4 = Label(frame3, text = "Title", width = 15)
    lbl4.pack(side = TOP, anchor=N, padx=5, pady=5)

    self.txt = Text(frame3)
    self.txt.pack(fill = BOTH, side = TOP, padx=5, pady=5, expand=True)
```

It creates something like this:
    [image]

And i want something looks like this. But i appriciate every idea:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't be afraid of googling about [pack manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and especially about [packer algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26), and after that try to understand why you get what you get.

Because of relatyvity in `pack` logic, it's not an easy task for beginner to control horizontal and vertical positioning of widgets. Hence, remember the "divide and conquer" principle and treat your program layout as a set of blocks, in any of which we place widget in horizontal order or in vertical order, without mixing.

Consider your layout, it looks like:
[image: layout]

Where each red block is a `Frame` widget + `Root` (or "master" `Frame`, feel free to create one) with one placing order.

To represent something like this try this snippet:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame()
frame1.pack()

for _ in range(2):
    i_frame = tk.Frame(frame1)

    label = tk.Label(i_frame, text='Sample%d' % _)
    label.pack(padx=200)

    entry = tk.Entry(i_frame)
    entry.pack(padx=200)

    i_frame.pack(side='left', ipady=25)

frame2 = tk.Frame()
frame2.pack()

label = tk.Label(frame2, text='Sample3')
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(frame2)
entry.pack()

label = tk.Label(frame2, text='Title', width=15)
label.pack()

txt = tk.Text(frame2)
txt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Also, remember, there's a [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) manager! With this manager you can treat layout as a table, so try it out too!

Comment: I'm not sure that, you are know what "divide and conquer" really means but i thanks for the respond. I can solve my problem with it. And thanks for the grid manager, I have not heard about it before.